# PHP - create new array for specific keys

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I have the following array, and I only want to return keys that are `carousel_`, NOT `_carousel_` or the word itself `carousel`:

```
Array ( 
    [test_field] => 

    [_test_field] => field_61d60b3a91441 

    [carousel_0_slide] => 42 

    [_carousel_0_slide] => field_61d35ea917c1b 

    [carousel_1_slide] => 42 

    [_carousel_1_slide] => field_61d35ea917c1b 

    [carousel_2_slide] => 42 

    [_carousel_2_slide] => field_61d35ea917c1b 

    [carousel_3_slide] => 42 

    [_carousel_3_slide] => field_61d35ea917c1b 

    [carousel] => 4 

    [_carousel] => field_61d35e3617c1a 
)
```

I've tried looping through it but I haven't been able to specifically target the `carousel_` without also including the rest, or really even correctly.

Any help would greatly be appreciated it.

Comment: use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) https://3v4l.org/GJQbd - you should add what you have tried

Comment: Do you want to include only the `carousel_ key` or it with `carousel_some_other_words`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that worked great! can you please post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

```
$keys = preg_grep('/^console_/',$your_array);
$my_array = [];
foreach ($keys as $k) {
    $my_array[$k] = $your_array[$k];
}
```